# parse : ParseObject One –to- Many Relationship

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I create a Table which contain: `Subject_code`, `Subject_name` and `Subject_section`(FK).

A subject have few sections (eg.lecturer sec,tut 1 sec, tut 2 sec ) , I need to create another `subject_section` table.

I want to link my `Subject_section` from this table with my previous table `subject_section`.
How do I link using Array or pointer in Parse?

Comment: What's your mean by `Table` ? SQLite table, data model, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new ParseClass "subject_section" with a pointer column "subject" and reference to related subject with it.

Code Example:

```
ParseQuery subjectQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Subject");
subjectQuery.whereEqualTo("Subject_name", subjectName);
subjectQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (object == null) {
            // object not found
        } else {
            ParseObject subjectSection = new ParseObject("SubjectSection");
            subjectSection.put("Subject", object);
            subjectSection.saveInBackground();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can u guide me how to code it ? 
Below I tried but unsuccessful. 
`final ParseObject object = new ParseObject("Subject"); 
object.put("Subject_code", code); 
object.put("Subject_name", name); 
final ParseObject object1=new ParseObject("Subject_section"); 
object1.put("Subject_section", section01); 
object1.put("Subject_section", section02);
object.saveInBackground(); 
object1.saveInBackground(); `

Comment: If you want to relate object1 with object, just put it in the field. `object1.put("subject", object);`

Comment: I tried still cant get it. 
I have few session(eg lec sess,tut sess) linking  to one subject, I cant put it in the same table, so I need to create another table pointing to that particular subject.

I know how to point my object to the user but I cant point my object to another table's object.
object.put("User",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

Comment: It's the same. Make sure the column field is setup as Pointer type to the specific class.

Comment: Can you write the code example ? I tried with object1.put("subject_section".getCurrentObject()); but have errors.The getCurrent only can work with ParseUser but not with ParseObject.